Try to replace old boost with new one in old code and get error, "type": is not a member of boost::mpl::eval_if
I tried to compile old code (~15 years old - luabind) that uses very old boost version (sth like 1.30) with new version of boost 1.86.
I replaced some apply_if usages with eval_if like it is suggested in release notes of boost 1.32. However I stuck on some compilation error. I tried to prepare some minimum example of that problematic code below.
#include <boost/mpl/end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
#include <boost/move/detail/meta_utils.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list/list10.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_and_derived.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/enum_params_with_a_default.hpp>

#include <iostream>

struct unspecified {
    typedef unspecified type;
};

template<class T, class X1 = unspecified, class X2 = unspecified, class X3 = unspecified>
struct class_;

double is_not_unspecified_helper(const unspecified*);
char is_not_unspecified_helper(...);

template<class T>
struct is_not_unspecified
{
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = sizeof(is_not_unspecified_helper(static_cast<T*>(0))) == sizeof(char));
    typedef boost::mpl::bool_<value> type;
    BOOST_MPL_AUX_LAMBDA_SUPPORT(1, is_not_unspecified, (T))
};

template<class Predicate>
struct get_predicate
{
    typedef typename boost::mpl::and_<
        Predicate
        , is_not_unspecified<boost::mpl::_1>
    > type;
};

template<class Parameters, class Predicate, class DefaultValue>
struct extract_parameter
{
    typedef typename get_predicate<Predicate>::type pred;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::find_if<Parameters, pred>::type iterator;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::is_same<iterator, typename boost::mpl::end<Parameters>::type>
        , boost::mpl::identity<DefaultValue>
        , iterator
    >::type type;
};


template<class T, class X1, class X2, class X3>
struct class_ {

    class_(const char* name)
    {
        std::printf("class_(%s)\n", name);
    }

    typedef typename extract_parameter<
        boost::mpl::list3<X1, X2, X3>
        , boost::mpl::or_<
            boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::mpl::_, T>
        ,   boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::mpl::_, T>
        >
        , unspecified
    >::type bases_t;
};

class A {
public:
    typedef A type;
};

class B :
    public A
{

public:
    typedef B type;

    void foo()
    {
        class_<B, A>("B");
    }
};

int main()
{
}

Compilation error:
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039: 'type': is not a member of 'boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::is_same<Iterator,LastIterator>,boost::mpl::identity<DefaultValue>,boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list3<X1,X2,X3>>>'
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:         with
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:         [
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:             Iterator=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list3<A,unspecified,unspecified>>,
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:             LastIterator=boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_end>,
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:             DefaultValue=unspecified,
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:             X1=A,
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:             X2=unspecified,
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:             X3=unspecified
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C2039:         ]
1>main.cpp(50,10): error C3646: 'type': unknown override specifier
1>main.cpp(50,5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>Done building project "eval_if_compilation.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

I'm pretty sure that the reason is related to extract_parameter::iterator type definition. When I replaced it with simply unspecified structure it compiles well. I belive that the reason is that it cannot find iterator::type type. However it is well defined and I don't understand why it results with error.

It looks like the wrapping identity<> around iterator is missing.
using type        = boost::mpl::eval_if<                                   //
    boost::is_same<iterator, typename boost::mpl::end<Parameters>>, //
    boost::mpl::identity<DefaultValue>,                             //
    boost::mpl::identity<iterator>                                  //
    >::type;

Makes it compile for me (fixing the includes).
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/move/detail/meta_utils.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/find_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/integral_c.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list/list10.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/enum_params_with_a_default.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_and_derived.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

struct unspecified {
    typedef unspecified type;
};

template<class T, class X1 = unspecified, class X2 = unspecified, class X3 = unspecified>
struct class_;

double is_not_unspecified_helper(const unspecified*);
char is_not_unspecified_helper(...);

template<class T>
struct is_not_unspecified
{
    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = sizeof(is_not_unspecified_helper(static_cast<T*>(0))) == sizeof(char));
    typedef boost::mpl::bool_<value> type;
    BOOST_MPL_AUX_LAMBDA_SUPPORT(1, is_not_unspecified, (T))
};

template<class Predicate>
struct get_predicate
{
    typedef typename boost::mpl::and_<
        Predicate
        , is_not_unspecified<boost::mpl::_1>
    > type;
};

template<class Parameters, class Predicate, class DefaultValue>
struct extract_parameter
{
    using pred        = typename get_predicate<Predicate>::type;
    using iterator    = typename boost::mpl::find_if<Parameters, pred>::type;
    using type        = boost::mpl::eval_if<                                   //
        boost::is_same<iterator, typename boost::mpl::end<Parameters>>, //
        boost::mpl::identity<DefaultValue>,                             //
        boost::mpl::identity<iterator>                                  //
        >::type;
};

template<class T, class X1, class X2, class X3>
struct class_ {

    class_(char const* name) { std::printf("class_(%s)\n", name); }

    typedef typename extract_parameter<
        boost::mpl::list3<X1, X2, X3>
        , boost::mpl::or_<
            boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::mpl::_, T>
        ,   boost::is_base_and_derived<boost::mpl::_, T>
        >
        , unspecified
    >::type bases_t;
};

class A {
public:
    typedef A type;
};

class B :
    public A
{

public:
    typedef B type;

    void foo()
    {
        class_<B, A>("B");
    }
};

int main()
{
}

